# Azure Data Factory : Square brackets in expression

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create a Lookup activity that relies on an **SQL query.**

the SQL query should be as follow (tested succesfully in SQL server) :

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE dbo.[Key]='someValue'
```

In ADF it should be as follows (escaping the single quotes) :

```
@replace('SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE dbo.[Key]=''{value}'')','{value}','someValue')
```

The column name `Key` needs to be between **square brackets** **[]** because `Key` is a reserved keyword of SQL. If I remove the square brackets, the SQL query is rejected by SQL server with message : `Invalid syntax near 'Key'`.

**Problem :**

When debugging the Pipeline, **ADF seems to be removing the square brackets.** I get this error :

```
The multi-part identifier "dbo.Key" could not be bound
```

**Troubleshooting :**

I tried this (double square brackets) **[[]]** :

```
@replace('SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE dbo.[[Key]]=''{value}'')','{value}','someValue')
```

I got a different error :

```
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '[Key]='someValue''.

Incorrect syntax near '[Key]='someValue''.
```

...I think all that achieved is to confuse SQL instead of fixing the expression work at ADF level.

**What's the correct way of making ADF respect the square brackets?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might not be because of brackets but because of the inconsistent quotes. If you can't detect the bad extra quote, as an alternative, you can try isolating the query from the rest to visualize it better, as shown in the below demonstration:

- The following is the table data that I am trying to query:

[image]

- When I used the following query in look up, I got the same error saying incorrect syntax near 'Key' (here value is a parameter with default value as 'C').

```
select * from t1 where Key='@{pipeline().parameters.value}'
```

[image]

- So, first store the query as a string in a variable using set variable activity.

```
select * from t1 where [Key]='@{pipeline().parameters.value}'
```

[image]

- Now, in the look up activity, use replace function to change the condition dynamically.

```
@replace(variables('query'),pipeline().parameters.value,'B')
```

[image]

- This would give the result as expected. The following is an output image for reference:

[image]

Comment: It's a nice solution (I will try it) but I should say: I feel like you're trying to dodge the bad escaping of square brackets by relying on an intermediary variable (which happens to somehow sanitize the string, as a side effect) instead of directly targeting the issue in ADF's expression syntax.

Comment: Hey @jeancallisti, the square brackets should not affect the query or syntax. I have used an intermediary variable to simplify the usage of replace since the error was indicating a problem with quotes as specified in the question.

Comment: OK. Right now I can't spot the bad quote but maybe I'll find it with your step-by-step debug technique. Maybe you should edit the first sentence of your reply and I will mark it as "accepted" : `The issue might not be because of brackets but because of the inconsistent quotes. If you can't detect the bad extra quote then you can try isolating the query from the rest to visualize it better, as shown in the below demonstration:`

Comment: Hey @jeancallisti, edited as suggested. I will try to give an update about where the bad quotes are present and causing the issue.

Comment: Can you add an image of the debug input of your look up activity where you are getting the error `Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '[Key]='someValue''`. For the case above, when I use the query `@replace('select * from t1 where [Key]=''C'')','C','B')` I get a different error. I get the correct output when I use the query as `@replace('select * from t1 where [Key]=''C''','C','B')`, I get the correct output.

Comment: Sorry @Saideep for the moment I have to put this on hold as I'm forced to work in another area of the workflow.